# #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE with iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

i have a problem, i want add different import file for iPhone and iPad, but for iPad doesnt' work, this is how i do:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import "MyView_iPhone.h"
#elif TARGET_OS_IPAD
#import "MyView_iPad.h"
#endif
```

when in the code then i write for example:

```
MyView_iPhone *iphone = [MyView_iPhone alloc] init];
```

works, but:

```
MyView_iPad *iphone = [MyView_iPad alloc] init];
```

doens't work, give me an error, because doens't see the MyView_iPad.h, how i can do?

this is the error:

Unknown receiver 'MyView_iPad'; did you mean 'MyView_iPhone'?

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: Beware that is in compile time and will not work in runtime.

Comment: i have add the error, i want also add that when i write #import "MyView_iPad.h" doens't give me the hint to complete code, but i have to add all myself...

Comment: Where does `TARGET_OS_IPAD` come from, I'm not convinced the system ever defines it for you. AFAIK, both use `TARGET_OS_IPHONE`.

Comment: i have find it here: http://cduu.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/differentiate-between-iphone-and-simulator/

Comment: check for device not for OS

Comment: @wasim how i can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<TargetConditionals.h>` does not actually define a `TARGET_OS_IPAD`. You can't know at compile time whether you're executing for iphone or ipad! That is something you should check at runtime, importing both views and doing something like:

```
UIView *iphone;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    iphone = [[MyView_iPad alloc] init];
}
    else{
    iphone = [[MyView_iPhone alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: i know that i can do in that way, but I thought it was better not to import files that were not needed, so i choose that way, but if you tell me that is not possible remove it...

Comment: Well, if you are actually building two separate targets for iphone and ipads, you can define your own preprocessor macro and use that one in your code. But if you're building a universal app then there's no way to do that at compile time.

Comment: Well, if there are separate view controllers for different target devices, then iPhone or iPad is known at compile time. If the interfaces are significantly different, then this may be the best approach.

Comment: @Piero you usually don't have to optimize on includes, it is done by the preprocessor for you.